# Google Analytics Opt-out option for users to be GDPR compliance

Tags: google-analytics, gdpr

We have GA installed on almost every website and with GDPR implementation we have to give user option to Opt-Out from google analytics.

I didnt fine any such option in GA which we can use rather there are few steps which we can setup in GA such as Block Advertisement, Make IP Anonymize, block

Most difficult one is to give user Opt-Out option. Is there an easy an reliable way of doing it.

or how we can block it using JavaScript, What are the other measure that we can take make GA compliance with GDPR

Answer (score -1):

As of today, I don't believe Google services can be considered EU GDPR compliant. With or without opt-out option.

**Further reading**

- **Full EU law & normative:** https://commission.europa.eu/law/law-topic/data-protection/data-protection-eu_en
- **Summary** *(If you don't have too much time)*: https://piwik.pro/blog/is-google-analytics-gdpr-compliant/

**Update (August 2023):**

"Third attempt of the European Commission to get a stable agreement on EU-US data transfers will be likely back at the Court of Justice (CJEU) in a matter of months. The allegedly "new" Trans-Atlantic Data Privacy Framework is largely a copy of the failed "Privacy Shield". Despite the European Commission's public relations efforts, there is little change in US law or the approach taken by the EU. The fundamental problem with FISA 702 was not addressed by the US, as the US still takes the view that only US persons are worthy of constitutional rights." (*Ref: https://noyb.eu/en/european-commission-gives-eu-us-data-transfers-third-round-cjeu*)

Comment: Are you affiliated with this site?

Comment: What question is that? They offer a clear and well documented explanation. Moreover, they offer a free solution for the EU market compliant to EU GDPR. It is very hard to find analytic services EU GDPR compliant, especially free like Google. Unfortunately, Google Analytics is not compliant to EU GDPR. Why don't you help to clarify this matter rather than criticising all my answers and leaving users exposed to legal risks?

Comment: Hi Goemon, I am sorry you took that as criticism.   The answers here are supposed to self-contained, to do that, you need to provide a summary here from that article.  And its good practice to declare your affiliation to any site you mention (whether or not you are associated with it).  If I was criticising it, I would have down-voted it.

Comment: Hi Rohit, if you do not read any declaration regarding any affiliation it can only mean that there isn't any affiliation :) If something provides some good value I would suggest it anyway. However, it looks like a couple of script kiddies who think to understand too much about networks, databases, and privacy in The E.U. downvoted my answer.  I have seen too many script kiddies underestimating the importance of personal data. It seems to be a waste of time to write here for sharing some knowledge.